# How can we create video frame with single image,pdf or doc file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to make video frame with different format like .doc,.pdf, and image. is it possible?

I found below command.
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg

but this will created with multiple images. I need video with single image.

Any suggestion.

Comment: But video, by its very nature, is composed of multiple images.

Comment: yes, this is the exact problem. thanks @Nick

Comment: Well, I have no idea what you're asking then.

Comment: want to make video with single image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
ffmpeg -y -r 24 -loop_input -vframes 240 -i img.jpg test.mpg
```

It should create a 10 second mpg at 24fps from a single input frame.